# Dynamically sorted table sort lost on update

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am creating a table dynamically using JQuery as the number of rows in the table depends on the amount of Agents configured to a server I am pulling data from.

The statistics in the table need to be "real-time" so I am recreating the table every second with fresh statistics. I am using the JQuery TableSorter plugin - http://tablesorter.com/docs/
to allow me to make the table sortable as is one of my requirements, However every time the table is recreated this renders the sort useless. Can anyone think of a solution?

This is my code to create the table.

```
function addToTable() { 

    var agentData = getAgentStats();
    var ids = getAgentIds();
    var names = getAgentNames();

    // Add new Row to to table
    for(var i =0;i<agentData.length;i++){ 

        $('#StatsContainer').append('<tr><td>'+ids[i]+'</td><td>'+names[i]+'</td><td>'+agentData[i].statistics[13]+'</td><td>'+agentData[i].statistics[3]+'</td>\n\
    <td>'+agentData[i].statistics[4]+'</td><td>'+agentData[i].statistics[6]+'</td><td>'+agentData[i].statistics[12]+'</td><td>'+agentData[i].statistics[14]+'</td><tr>'); 
    }

    // Let table sorter know that table contents has changed 
    $("table").trigger("update");
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does this render the sort useless?

Comment: Can you include some more code? Maybe the HTML of your table and the javascript where you initialize it?

Comment: Maybe consider trying out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), when you trigger an [update](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#update), it will automatically resort the table using the last sort.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code to gain context:

Tablesorter supports the ability to send it controls about how you want to sort the table.

```
$("#trigger-link").click(function() { 
     // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column the column index starts at zero 
     var sorting = [[0,0],[2,0]]; 
     // sort on the first column 
     $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
     // return false to stop default link action 
     return false; 
 });
```

You could intercept clicks on headers to take note of the sort order, and then call on tablesorter as demonstrated above.

Once you are intercepting how the table should be sorted you can apply that sort after every time you rebuild the table.